# SharePoint 2007 storage and permissions limitation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Our organization is using SharePoint 2007 as knowledge management system.
We need to analyze the limitations of our SharePoint. We need to supply information about what is the maximum storage (GB) we can manage in a single site collection / web application without damaging performance / causing the site collection / web application to crash down.
Also we need to supply information of how many unique permissions we can manage without damaging performance.
Anyone knows how can I get this information ? I searched in Google but found only limitation of site collections in a web application but not storage for site collection / web application.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think the limit is 100GB for databases, although it's not a fixed limit, rather a guide.

Your limits are going to be determined by your hardware, configuration and number of users.

What is acceptable performance for you?

Comment: Do you mean 100GB per WSS Content (Web application) ?
I need limitation information which is recomended by Microsoft / People that have experience with SharePoint 2007

Comment: 100GB  / Content database. I have some experience in this area, we just migrated from 2007 to 2010. I have 3 DB's with roughly that amount of content in them, and the performance is acceptable.

Comment: sorry, I just want to be sure I understand, content database represents a total web application (with site collection in it) ?

Comment: No content databases are the SQL Server databases which store the data from site collections. You can have multiple content databases per web application. Typically I have 1 content database / site collection. Also generally only 1 web application.

Comment: This is what you're looking for I believe: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(office.12).aspx